# Traveling with a cat to the UK

Tags: uk, pets

I tried reserving a plane ticket with KLM yesterday, from Germany to the UK, and everything went great until I mentioned I'd be flying with a cat.

The KLM employee on the phone informed me the UK has a policy in place which prohibit taking pets into the UK, but not out of the UK.
Unfortunately, she couldn't provide me with more info.
I did my best to find more information online, but I was unable to find anything. The closest thing was a [gov.UK page](https://www.gov.uk/bring-pet-to-uk) listing the things a pet will **need** to have to be allowed inside the UK.

Is this policy in place for air traffic only?

If yes, what's the best alternative way to travel with a cat from Germany to the UK.
If not, is the policy set hard in stone? Or are am I allowed to travel with a pet via plane if certain requirements are met?

EDIT:

I'm travelling on 1st of December.

From reading all the answers I think driving there might be the best solution. Thank you all for answering!

Comment: There is a web page about this: https://www.gov.uk/bring-pet-to-uk Does that answer your question?

Comment: I suspect KLM are giving you the runaround. Or you just got an agent that doesn't know what they are talking about. The rules are the same until 1 January 2021, and even then, KLM are still an approved carrier to bring cats into the UK.

Comment: You should be aware that the rules are very strict. The UK is rabies-free, and will spend a lot of effort to keep it that way.

Comment: Are you moving there, or just visiting and want to take your cat? You are likely to get more information about moving with your cat on Expatriates. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The UK is very strict when it comes to travelling with pets, and many carriers apparently think it's not worth the hassle. Even British Airways won't accept any pets. Note that this is not specific to airlines, Eurostar won't accept pets either. I have to admit I have no idea what means of transport would enable you to bring your cat (ferries? Eurotunnel shuttle?).

Comment: Did KLM actually say they wouldn't carry your pet, or did they just want to make sure you knew about the rules?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "The rules are the same until 1 January 2021..." I thought the same thing. Do you have any proof of the KLM being the approved carrier? I would love to look into it more.

Comment: @KateGregory I am planning to move there, just wasn't aware there was expat type of a SE. Should I repost there? I thought there wouldn't be much of a difference between traveling and moving.

Comment: @DJClayworth I did read up on that webpage, but from my undestanding of it, as long as I provide the documents I'm allowed to bring the pet in.  
As a responce to your second comment. When I spoke to their employee it sounded like they wouldn't mind taking the pet, but UK policy was againt bringing in the pets to the UK. I made sure my pet fits the requirements found on their webpage. [travelling with pets - KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/de_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/pets/index.htm)

Comment: They're on the [official list](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/pet-travel-approved-air-sea-rail-and-charter-routes-for-the-movement-of-pets/approved-air-routes-for-pet-travel).

Comment: Yes, if you follow the rules on that page you are allowed to bring the pet into the UK. KLM may have additional restrictions on whether (and how) they will carry the pet, but that doesn't affect the UK import rules. What exactly is it you are asking?

Comment: @DJClayworth In regard to the UK policy, what's the best way to bring a pet into the UK?

Comment: Here's BAs take on it. Any pets they carry must go in the hold:
https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/travel-assistance/travelling-with-pets

Comment: It's normal in Europe that pets travel in the hold. If your pet fits the requirements then most airlines will be OK with carrying them. But also if you aren't coming to Britain long term it may be best to leave your pet at home.

Comment: None of this is particularly new. In the mid 80s, we were moving from the US to Israel and took our dogs. We were to have a layover (not a change of plane) in England (Heathrow, I suspect) until we discovered that the dogs would be removed from the hold and kept in quarantine for 14 days. We rebooked our flights to a direct flight to avoid England entirely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For some reason, it's very difficult to bring a pet into the UK by air in the cabin. I have researched this, and it's unclear why this is the case. In theory, the law is harmonised across the EU, and allows pets up to 8kg including carrier to fly in the cabin. In practice, no scheduled flights into the UK seem to actually allow this.

The best option will be dependent on your specific circumstances. Although Eurostar does not allow pets, the Eurotunnel Shuttle service [does allow them](https://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/travelling-with-us/travelling-with-your-pet/). But of course, you need to be travelling in a private vehicle to use the Shuttle. Similarly, many ferry operators do as well, but again only in private vehicles. If you have the ability to drive, the Shuttle or a ferry are the best option.

According to this well researched page from The Man in Seat 61 [a few ferry operators](https://www.seat61.com/dogs-by-train.htm) do allow pets on specific routes for foot passengers however

> In fact, there are only three ferry operators who let foot passengers take dogs, Stena Line Harwich to Hoek van Holland, P&O Hull-Rotterdam, DFDS Newhaven-Dieppe & Newcastle-Amsterdam.

The Man in Seat 61 gives an alternative train route, which is to take the train to Calais, taking a taxi through the Eurotunnel, and then a train onwards from Folkestone.

Note that the regulations for bringing pets across the UK border may be disrupted by Brexit, from the 1st January 2021. Additionally, it's possible that some services allowing pets might be disrupted by the pandemic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll definietly consider the option you suggested.

Comment: A taxi through the Eurotunnel? Has that been done?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, see the page I linked, and also here http://www.folkestonetaxi.com/Pet+travel+abroad.html

Comment: Last I checked DFDS allows cats+dogs on all channel routes. The animal must remain in the vehicle however

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Brittany ferries also have kennels on their boats, but I don't know how this applies to cats or foot passengers; also their sailings are very limited at the moment

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Yes, as I said, all (?) ferry operators allow pets if you're travelling by car. There's only a few that will allow pets for pedestrians though, which is why I highlighted these.

Comment: How about flying to Ireland instead and then going to the UK via Northern Ireland? Perhaps that's easier?

Comment: @JonathanReez I'll look into it as an option, but I feel like getting a ride there might be the easiest solution. Both for my wallet and for my pet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

I brought a cat into England by car from France in 2016. The cat had an embedded microchip, and a European pet passport. I came by car ferry, and I had to report to the animal hut before boarding.

Having said that, it seems that these days you also need to have had your cat treated for tapeworm no more than five days before travel -- see [this link](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/unitedkingdom/en/about-us/publicinterest/travel/petpassport.html#:%7E:text=As%20an%20EU%20national%2C%20you,a%20valid%20anti%2Drabies%20vaccination.).

As for flying, I would say forget it.

Comment: Tapeworm treatment is not actually required for cats (says UK govt page, to which original poster links), but rabies is!

Comment: @domen: My link (www.europarl.europa.eu) says unambiguously that all animals require tapeworm treatment; the OP's link (www.gov.uk) says unambiguously that only dogs need it. So I suppose you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I have read that page before and it does say that. Someone should let them know to fix the info.

Comment: @domen: Now you're not making yourself clear again! By 'that page', do you mean the europa.eu one, or the gov.uk one?

Comment: Haha. Europa one (well both, in fact). Anyway, what I wanted to say was that it's nothing personal, just the europa.eu webpage with wrong info. Anecdotally we've also traveled with a cat a couple times, following gov.uk webpage guidance.

Answer (score 9):

We have dogs.  We considered taking them with us when we went on a trip to Luxembourg last year, but the trouble (and cost) of getting them back in the country meant it was much cheaper to put them in kennels for 2 weeks instead.

With Britain being an island, many of the diseases which are common in Europe are simply not present here (or at least not common), and there have been major efforts (especially with rabies) to make it that way and keep it that way.  The EU "pet passport" scheme has made this a little easier, but some treatments still need to be given immediately before crossing.  At the moment the EU "pet passport" scheme does not have an alternative for after Brexit either.  On 1st December you should be OK, but you can expect there to be problems after 31st December.

Policies for animals are 100% set in stone though, and there is no possibility of negotiation.  Airlines, ferries and Eurotunnel will refuse to carry you and your pet if you don't have the proof from a vet that your pet has had the necessary vaccinations/pills/whatever.  Or worst-case, if you get stopped on the other side then you have a choice either of going straight home again or having your pet destroyed.

Comment: Even with all the paperwork etc, many airlines as well as Eurostar won't accept any pets, full stop.

Answer (score 7):

I've been there and you're right, it's really complicated. Here's what I've learned. First, you *can* fly a cat into the UK, but you must have it [sent as cargo](https://www.gov.uk/bring-pet-to-uk/approved-routes):

> Pets usually travel as cargo, but there are different rules if you’re arriving by air or sea with an assistance dog.

This means that it will fly on the same flight you are on, but you need a separate ticket for the animal, one that is significantly more expensive than your own, and you need to fly into an airport that has freight handling. You also need to fly with an airline that handles freight, so low cost ones are out. [Here is the gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/pet-travel-approved-air-sea-rail-and-charter-routes-for-the-movement-of-pets/approved-air-routes-for-pet-travel) listing the airlines that can do this and the airports they fly to that can handle cargo of this sort.

The cat will travel as luggage, as freight, and not be in the cabin with you. What's worse, although you might think it kind to drug the cat so it sleeps through its ordeal, we were advised not to do this because the people checking the cat on arrival won't run any proper blood tests, they just look at the state the animal is in. And if it looks like it's sick, for instance if it is waking up after a few hours on sleeping pills, they may quarantine it. Which will be no fun for anyone involved.

Your other option is to go by car or train. However, You can't just take it with you on the Eurostar. No, you need to take a special train that carries vehicles. Those are the only ones that carry "freight" and cats are apparently in this category. More detail on that in [this gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/pet-travel-approved-air-sea-rail-and-charter-routes-for-the-movement-of-pets/pet-travel-sea-routes-and-companies-you-can-use) about sea and rail routes.

In the end, we chose to pay the ~500€ ticket and fly the cat from Athens to London as cargo. We delivered it to the airport, it was taken away, and then on arrival we had to go pick it up from a special place in Heathrow. On the bright side, the cat was actually fine. It was obviously unhappy but not scarred for life or anything, and it was its normal haughty self a couple of days later. So it is probably less traumatic than it sounds.

My advice to you is to ask your airline. Tell them you need to send the cat as freight and ask them how much such a ticket would cost. And make sure you carefully read through *every step* of this step by step guide to bringing your pet to the UK: https://www.gov.uk/bring-pet-to-uk

Comment: The key point here seems to be that the cat can't fly in the cabin on a commercial flight. Annoying and expensive and probably pointless, but that seems to be the rules.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep, exactly. You also need a very large carrier, for some reason I don't remember and I can't find a reference for now. But we had to buy a special one that would fit a medium dog! Granted, that may have been overkill, I don't remember the details on this.

Comment: When flew our cats the other direction (from UK to US) we were advised against drugging them as there was no way to help them if they had an adverse reaction during the flight.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to drive with the cat in your own car, and use the Eurotunnel “Le Shuttle” service, which is pet-friendly. As an added bonus, I believe that under current UK COVID-19 rules, you won’t need to self-isolate upon arrival in the UK if you don’t get out of your car (and no one else gets in) while you’re in a country other than Germany or the UK. Of course, this doesn’t help much if you don’t have a car.

Comment: We have done this multiple times and I agree this is probably the least stressful way for a cat. Regarding self-isolation, it might be tricky, as you need to get out of the car for pet check-in, and that's in France, even before border control. Maybe "drive through" pet reception is an option, for which you apparently need to pay extra.